# How to get the first value of class attribute of a tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say the body tag has a few class attributes:

```
<body class="html logged-in frontpage no-sidebar">
...
</body>
```

Currently, I use jQuery to get all class attributes of body tag using:

```
$('body').attr('class');
```

I want to get the very beginning/first class attribute (which is 'html' class here).
How?

Comment: Generally you shouldn't need this. The `class` attribute is usually treated as an unordered set of strings, and jQuery generally affords such usage. (Using [`.hasClass()` and friends](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/).

Comment: nice. thanks for mentioning hasClass()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('body').attr('class').split(" ")[0];
```

You could also use plain old javascript (see Vega's answer)

Answer (score 3):

Try like below,

```
//Using document.body
document.body.className.split(' ')[0]
```